# What is the best strategy for after hours trading?

Tags: united-states, investing, stock-exchanges, online-trading, after-hours-trading

I'm new to stock market trading and while I do understand the basic concepts; researching the companies, buy low/sell high, and including setting good push/pull calls for both high and low margins.

I would like to know if there is anyone that can give me advice for trading on NYSE/NASDAQ doing after hours since my work hours are typically aligned with TSE, HKSE, SSE, SGX?

You may ask why I pick the NYSE/NASDAQ, well I'm american born citizen and do not want to deal with the overhead cost/political landmines of dealing with foreign exchanges at this point in my trading career. However I am open to all suggestions and will be doing my trading through an online platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a plan stating three main points:

1. What to buy?
2. When to buy?
3. When to sell?

You will have to decide what criteria you will use to answer these points. You might use Fundamental Analysis to find what to buy and Technical Analysis to decide when to buy and when to sell (your buy and sell triggers).

Once you have a Trading Plan in place you would need to find a broker with conditional orders. You can place conditional buy orders to get in a trade (for example if the price moves above or below a target price). You can place conditional stop loss orders if your trade goes against you, and you can also place conditional profit target stops to automatically get out if rises to your desired profit target.

You can place one, two or many conditional orders after hours which will enable you to trade without being in front of your screen all day long.

Answer (score 2):

I would never trade after hours and I have 30 years of trading experience.  It is a very volatile emotion driven market without a lot of the big players that arbitrage wrong pricing.

If I were you I would simply use limit orders you input while the market is closed.   If you want to get kute you can put in low-ball offers (and vice versa) to see if they get filled in the volatility at market open.  Then check in (when?) when you wake up (or before you go to bed, etc) and revise the limit if not filled.

In other words don't 'trade'.  Know what your company is worth and put in orders that reflect that.

Comment: +1 - Never do market orders for after hours trading. Because of the far more limited number of buyers/sellers you could end up selling your $100 stock for a $1. Likewise, you could end up buying the $1 stock for a $100. However, your chances of doing the same (by being on the plus side of this anomaly) are next to zero because the brokerages doing the buying/selling have software in place that will snag those orders up for their own coffers long before they process your order.